# Iterating over 2 elements in a list but repeating the second element in the next iteration

Tags: python, list

How do I make a for loop or a list comprehension so that every iteration gives me two elements but the last value must be repeated.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i,k in ???:
    print str(i), '+', str(k), '=', str(i+k)
```

Output:

```
1+2=3
2+3=5
3+4=7
4+5=9
...
```

Comment: It seems that ① you're learning Python ② you're learning Python 2. Python 2 has reached its [End of Life](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) and is no more mantained. You can do yourself a favour and drop Python 2 for Python 3.

Comment: @gboffi what makes you think the above code is python 2??

Comment: `print str(i), '+', str(k), '=', str(i+k)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i,k in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print(f'{i} + {k} = {i+k}')
```

Output:

```
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 3 = 5
3 + 4 = 7
4 + 5 = 9
5 + 6 = 11
```

For more explanation:

```
>>> list(zip(l, l[1:]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with a one-off slice:

```
for i, k in zip(l, l[1:]):
    # ...
```

But in Python >= 3.10 you also have [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
from itertools import pairwise

for i, k in pairwise(l):
    # ...
```

This is more space-efficient because it avoids the in-memory list produced by the slice. It can also be used with any iterator/iterable which helps avoid a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with standard indexing:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(1,len(l)):
    print( str(l[i-1]), '+', str(l[i]), '=', str(l[i] + l[i-1]) )
```

Output:

```
1 + 2 = 3
2 + 3 = 5
3 + 4 = 7
4 + 5 = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can also do it like this :-**

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in l:
    print (i, '+', i+1, '=',i+i+1)
```